# Passing properties to Android library project build file

Tags: android, ant, build

I have an Android app project that is split into a free and a paid version. Everything that is common to both projects resides in an Android library project called "core". Then I have actual Android app projects for both the paid and the free version.

I'm using Ant scripts for building these two APKs. The paid version sets a property that tells the "core" project that the paid version is building. The free version tells the core project that the free version is building.

That used to work perfectly fine until Google decided to release ADT 22. Now the "core" project doesn't pick up these build properties anymore.

I suspect that library projects are built in a separate Ant build environment / process now.

So here's my question: how do I define properties for referenced Android library projects within an app project's build.xml file? How to pass over properties to these library project builds?

And where in the SDK's build.xml file are library projects actually compiled? I guess that would be the right spot to look into.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you describe what these properties are for? Perhaps there is an alternative solution...(p.s. I feel your pain. I have been struggling with the exact same situation trying to build two versions of an app without duplicating too much code.)

Comment: @Code-Guru I agree, it's painful. And I remember having struggled with that half a year ago and every time when ADT gets a major update you have to rework that build script. To answer your question: these properties are used to create a dynamically generated Java class file with static boolean flags. These flags are used for switching  on / off code portions in the core project. These two flags are "IS_PAID_VERSION" for activating the licensing validation code and the other one "IS_DEBUG" for activating very verbose logging.

Comment: I have got the same problem, any recent solution?

Comment: @nish1013 I edited my answer below to make it a little clearer how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT for clarification**

You have to create a modified copy of the original `build.xml` file from the Android SDK (see `SDK-Folder/tools/ant`) and also keep it up to date every now and again when Google releases an ADT update by merging the differences (and keeping the own modifications of course).

The `build.xml` file builds library projects using a `<subant>` task, which basically starts a separate build environment that does not automatically see any properties of the calling scope (which would be the app project's build environment).

However, within that `subant` tag you can export properties of the caller's scope to the library's build XML using a `<propertyset>` tag. Look for the following code block in your copy of `build.xml` and make a modification as shown below:

```
....
            <echo level="info">Building Libraries with '${project.libraries.target}'...</echo>

            <!-- no need to build the deps as we have already
                 the full list of libraries -->
            <subant failonerror="true" buildpathref="project.library.folder.path" antfile="build.xml">

                <!-- *** ADD THIS: *** -->
                <propertyset id="project.library.buildargs">
                    <propertyref prefix="project.library.buildargs" />
                </propertyset>

                <target name="nodeps" />
                <target name="${project.libraries.target}" />
                <property name="emma.coverage.absolute.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/coverage.em" />
            </subant>
....
```

Above example makes all app project `build.xml` properties that are prefixed with `project.library.buildargs.` visible to all referenced Android library build scripts.

Comment: The question is how to set/pass a property that is accessible from library build.xml. In my case I have different environments needs to be passed from the project to library project's build.xml

Comment: @nish1013 You may have noticed that I was the one asking the original question. This answer of mine solves the problem. You have to create a copy of the original Android Ant `build.xml` file (see Android SDK) and modify it by finding the code block shown above (with that echo line saying "Building Libraries with..."). Then you need to embed into that `subant` task a `propertyset` tag. That will expose any properties defined inside to the `subant` task build environment (in this case all Android library projects). Just add a `propertyref` tag in that `propertyset` as shown in my answer.

Comment: too bad it requires a build system modification :(

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution I have found to provide different values for my free version vs my paid version is to use [resources]. The Android build chain allows application projects to override the resource values set in the shared library project.

So for example, you can have a boolean resource in any XML file in `res/values`:

```
<bool name="paid_version">false</bool>
```

Of course, the paid version has the same resource in its own `res/values` subdirectory with a value of `true`.

Then from an `Activity` subclass or any other class with a `Context`, you can do the following:

```
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.id.paid_version)) {
    // Do the paid version code here
}
```

This has the advantage that it is fairly easy to implement. On the down side, this is a run-time check based on dynamic code. This means that the code cannot be optimized away by the compiler or any other static analysis tool when the resource value is set to `false`.

Comment: That's genius! But I wonder if ProGuard is able to strip out these code portions when the condition is "false". As far as I know it is able to remove "dead" code hidden in if-blocks that always evaluate to "false". I believe a requirement for that to work is that the if statement condition must not contain variable references or method calls so it can be evaluated at compile time. But anyway, I'll think of that simpler solution in future projects. You can also use it for configuring things, like setting up API keys or URLs for help pages or stuff like that... the possibilities :-D

Comment: @NobuGames That is a good point. I will edit a critique into my answer.